# files crash after i try to downsample them with scipy

Tags: python, audio, scipy, wav, downsampling

I have a wav of the following youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glOnDceqqJc

which has 44100Hrz and has the length of 2 minutes and I want to downsample it to 16000Hrz
my script works on shorter files but when I run my script with this file It's file grows from 21mb to 30mb and I get a format error when I try to run  it.

here is my script:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.signal import resample

def resamplee(file):
    try:
        sampling_rate, wv = wavfile.read(file)
        if sampling_rate == 16000:
            pass
        else:
            sec = len(wv)/sampling_rate
            nsmp = int(sec * 16000) + 1
            resamp = resample(wv,nsmp)
            wavfile.write(file,16000,resamp)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

resamplee('audio.wav')
```

can someone explain to me what is going wrong or how can I fix this? 
thanks!

Comment: Can you share someplace the file you are using?